# Port Forwarding on Rpi3 for remote access not working

Tags: pi-3, networking, remote, dns, port-forwarding

I want to access my Rpi3 from anywhere. For that i have created an Free account on noip.com. I have a my Hostname too. I am using O2 Router at home, and also setup for DynDNS  as well as Port Forwarding.

But once I configure my Hostname with port, that i open in Router, noip.com says **Port is not open, we can't connect**. I tried with different port and finally i got one open port(port 22). With port 22 i can successfully configure my hostname. So now my Problem is :

1. Why only one Port(port 22) is working not other ?
2. After successful configure my Hostname, if i try to open my webpage with my hostname on browser, It says **There is no connection on this IP. Safari can't connect.**

Every help and suggestion should be Thankful. :)

Comment: If you want to connect via safari I assume you have a web server on the pi and you forwarded port 80 right?

Comment: @matteo yes, I have install web Server on Pi but i am not forwarding port 80. is it necessary to forwarding port 80 only ?

Comment: If you want to access a web server on port 80 you need to forward port 80, same for ssh on port 22

Comment: The Pi seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your router, not the RPi.

Comment: @Dmitry I think the same before but i tried even with another Router(My friend's house) but it still remain same. What i think is, i am using free No-ip account for a while, that may be has some limitation. and i have to buy some package for few months and will try then. Is there any limitation in Free No-ip account ?